# When do people explode?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Sometimes, I noticed that when I'm in hand to hand combat, a small explosion happens when they die.  When is this scenario triggered?  And how much damage does it do?

Comment: Typically when they have anger management issues.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Or are suddenly dropped into a very low pressure zone.

Comment: Man, now I'm mad. I was hoping to see how do people explode. :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe what you are referring to is a new property of the Zoltan.  They now explode on death, dealing 15 damage to nearby hostile forces (not systems/hull).

According to [this wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Races/Zoltan), Zoltan explosions harm hostiles in an entire room, not just who killed them.

If you have noticed it with other species, let me know because that would be something different that I am not aware of.

Comment: I haven't been paying too close attention to the explosions, I thought I saw something else explode when dying but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, verify this if you see it with other races; it should just be the Zoltan.

Comment: interesting, so it only harms hostiles? Does it damage systems?  I might play around with suicidal zoltan bombers in one of my playthroughs with an upgraded cloning bay.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it does not damage systems or hull.  Also, yes, it only harms hostile crew members.

Comment: Bizarrely, Zoltan explosions are now in the base game, once you've downloaded the AE patch, even with AE disabled.

Comment: It looks like the explosions do 15 damage.  At least that's what one did to my mantis